# Anyone have experience using .NET based Glorsoft Velocity for IVR Development?

Tags: .net, ivr

Glorsoft Velocity is .Net based but I don't see a developer forum around it.  it is difficult to tell how well it is being adopted.  Product looks good to me but I only want to use a technology only if has a following and user group around it.  Anybody using it?  If so, how is it going for you?

Comment: We have decided to use the Glorsoft Velocity solution for our IVR development. The support is very responsive including during off-hours. We are not forced to use a strict graphical or XML environment imposed by a vendor or a standard (as in XML) but rather you are using standard .net classes in Visual Studio. They were awarded the Internet Telephony Export Best Of Show Aware for 2011. Link to Article is Here: http://www.ivrsworld.com/ivr-news/glorsoft-wins-internet-telephony-expo-2011-best-of-show-award-for-best-development-tool/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We’ve been using Glorsoft Velocity to build an IVR application (A Major Hospital in Cleveland Ohio, US) It has been a fantastic experience, we have a team of .Net developers and we were asked to build an IVR application. We had no experience in our group with IVR but set out to evaluate products that allow our current team to build what was needed.  During our evaluation one of our developers came across Glorsoft Velocity and was able to download and install a free trial, he then was able to build a working prototype IVR application in just a few hours. We spent about 4 weeks evaluating IVR Software, API’s and SDK’s before we came across Glorsoft Velocity and it took about two days of using it to make the decision to buy it (probably one of the first unanimous decisions our team has ever made)

The satisfaction with the software did not stop with the purchase either.  We on several occasions needed support.  Not for issues with the software but just because we had questions on how to get some things done.  The support was fantastic and done almost 100% through email (they did try and call us once but we never connected) it was quick; it was very helpful and very good, the best I have ever had in 30 years of dealing with a software company.  At one point we did manage to stump them with something that the software couldn’t do (because it was a hardware issue) and they managed to release a maintenance release that solved the hardware issue with our dialogic boards.

Our IVR is a windows service with 4 dedicated T-1’s running across two servers servicing about 60,000 calls a day.  We have absolutely no issues with the product or support it is world class.

Comment: We have decided to use the Glorsoft Velocity solution for our IVR development. The support is very responsive including during off-hours. We are not forced to use a strict graphical or XML environment imposed by a vendor or a standard (as in XML) but rather you are using standard .net classes in Visual Studio. They were awarded the Internet Telephony Export Best Of Show Aware for 2011. Link to Article is Here: http://www.ivrsworld.com/ivr-news/glorsoft-wins-internet-telephony-expo-2011-best-of-show-award-for-best-development-tool/